# Sequelize multiple foreignKey

Tags: javascript, database, sequelize.js

i have tables "Trades" and "Users"
so user can have multiple trades.

user can be buyer or seller.

i am trying to define this in sequelize like this

in trades

```
Trades.associate = models => {

    Trades.belongsTo(models.UserData, {
            targetKey: 'customId',
            as: 'buyer',
            foreignKey: 'buyerId'
    })
    Trades.belongsTo(models.UserData, {
            targetKey: 'customId',
            as: 'seller',
            foreignKey: 'sellerId'
    })
}
```

and in Users

```
UserData.associate = models => {

    UserData.hasMany(models.Trades, {
        foreignKey: 'buyerId',
        sourceKey: 'customId'
    })
    UserData.hasMany(models.Trades, {
        foreignKey: 'sellerId',
        sourceKey: 'customId'
    })
}
```

when i do findOne by customId in "Users" Table and include db "Trades", i want to have all information when user is a trader and seller, but  it gives me only when user is seller.

```
        let user = await UserData.findOne({where:{
                customId: req.user.customId
            }, include: 'Trades'
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use aliases for each relationships.
Here is the link : https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#defining-an-alias

But simply put you have to do something like :

```
UserData.hasMany(models.Trades, {
        foreignKey: 'buyerId',
        sourceKey: 'customId',
        as: 'Buyer'
    })
    UserData.hasMany(models.Trades, {
        foreignKey: 'sellerId',
        sourceKey: 'customId',
        as: 'Seller'
    })
```

And then, when you include :

```
let user = await UserData.findOne({where:{
                customId: req.user.customId
            }, include: ['Seller', 'Buyer']
        });
```

You can also ask Sequelize to do the includes based on the associations instead of the model :

```
include: [
{ association: Trades.associations.Seller }
]
```

PS: In the docs they don't pass an array to the include but in my version using typescript it's mandatory to do so. So I let you manage for that point!